# How do you set a minimum window size in x11?

Tags: x11, xorg

I do not see a function that tells x11 what minimum size you want a window to be, but there must be some sort of functionality for this. Firefox for example only lets you shrink the size of your window to a certain point. Is there some way to set the minimum size of a x11 window? I can't seem to google this problem either.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is how to set the minimum size of your X11 window to be 200x200:

```
XSizeHints* sizeHints = XAllocSizeHints();
sizeHints->flags = PMinSize;
sizeHints->min_width = 200;
sizeHints->min_height = 200;
XSetWMNormalHints(m_display, m_window, sizeHints);
XFree(sizeHints);
```

For whatever reason, I thought it would be more complicated, but it really isn't. To note, if you had a previously set maximum window size, this would erase that requirement. If you want to keep both a max and min window size, you will need to set both every time you do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can call XSetWMNormalHints to set a bunch of info about the window.

Here are the docs for XSetWMNormalHints: https://metacpan.org/pod/X11::Xlib#XSetWMNormalHints

> Set window manager hints for the specified window. $hints is an instance of X11::Xlib::XSizeHints, or a hashref of its fields. Note that the ->flags member of this struct will be initialized for you if you pass a hashref, according to what fields exist in the hashref.

The XSizeHints is a struct that allows you to specify the actual values.

Here are the docs for XSizeHints: https://metacpan.org/pod/X11::Xlib::XSizeHints

> The fields of the struct are as follows (from X11 docs)
>
> ```
> long flags;         /* marks which fields in this structure are defined */
> int x, y;           /* obsolete for new window mgrs, but clients */
> int width, height;  /* should set so old wm's don't mess up */
> int min_width, min_height;
> int max_width, max_height;
> int width_inc, height_inc;
> struct {
>     int x;  /* numerator */
>     int y;  /* denominator */
> } min_aspect, max_aspect;
> int base_width, base_height;  /* added by ICCCM version 1 */
> int win_gravity;              /* added by ICCCM version 1 */
> ```

> The values for flags ... can be an ORed combination of:
>
> ```
> USPosition   /* user specified x, y */
> USSize       /* user specified width, height */
> PPosition    /* program specified position */
> PSize        /* program specified size */
> PMinSize     /* program specified minimum size */
> PMaxSize     /* program specified maximum size */
> PResizeInc   /* program specified resize increments */
> PAspect      /* program specified min and max aspect ratios */
> PBaseSize    /* program specified base for incrementing */
> PWinGravity  /* program specified window gravity */
> ```

You need to set the min_width and min_height and set the flags to PMinSize.